# Why Shiva getting angry when Devi Sati get cremated?

Tags: shiva, sati

Shiva is considered as supreme god and he is beyond time. In other words time is controlled by Shiva and he is Aadi Yogi (Most controlled and calm).
So, he already know what will happen next.

So my question is **when Devi sati getting self-immolation which thing trigger most to Shiva to getting angry and started destroying everything ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all Lila.  Daksha had to be taught a lesson and when it was done, everybody was restored.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226062.html

> Brahmā said:—

1. Lord Śiva was delighted on being conciliated and cajolled by Viṣṇu, Brahmā and the sages.

> 2. Consoling Viṣṇu and other devas and laughing, the merciful lord Śiva blessed them and spoke.

> Lord Śiva said:—
> 3. O excellent devas, both of you listen with attention. O dear ones, I shall state the truth. I have always borne your wrath.

> 4. I do not take into account the sin committed by my children. I have inflicted punishment on those who are afflicted by my illusion.

> **5. The destruction of the sacrifice of Dakṣa was not done by me. If a person hates another, ultimately it recoils on him alone.

> 6. No action that involves the affliction of others will be indulged in by me at any time. If anyone hates another it will recoil on him alone.**

> 7. Let the head (the sacrificial head) of Dakṣa be that of a goat. Let the god Bhaga receive his share in the sacrifice in conjunction with the sun.

> 8. O dear ones, the god Pūṣan who used to grip the cooked offerings in a sacrifice with his teeth has been rendered broken-toothed and will remain as such. I have spoken the truth.

> 9. Bhṛgu who opposed me shall become goat-bearded. The gods who tried to uproot me shall have their physical bodies.

> 10. Let the Adhvaryu priests be borne through the arms of Aśvins and the hands of Pūṣan. I have spoken thus out of love for you.

> Brahmā said:—
> 11. Saying thus, the lord Śiva though merciful, yet of imperial nature, the lord of the mobile and immobile and the follower of Vedic injunctions, stopped.

> 12. On hearing his speech, Viṣṇu and other gods were delighted and sent out cries of approbation.

> 13-14. Then at the invitation of Viṣṇu and other gods, Śiva went to Kanakhala at the sacrificial altar of Dakṣa Prajāpati. The celestial sages and I too accompanied him there.

> 15. Then Rudra saw the extent of destruction carried out by Vīrabhadra, of the sacrifice and of the celestial sages.

> 16-17. Svāhā, Svadhā, Pūṣan, Tuṣṭi, Dhṛti, Sarasvatī, the sages, the manes, Agnis, many others like Yakṣas, Gandharvas, Rākṣasas who were mutilated, wounded or killed in the battle were seen by him laughingly.

> 18. On seeing this destruction of the sacrifice, He called the chieftain of Gaṇas, Vīrabhadra of great virility and spoke to him.

> 19. O Vīrabhadra of powerful arms, what is it that you have done? O dear, in your hurry you have inflicted very severe punishment on the celestial sages and others.

> 20. Bring Dakṣa here quickly. O dear, **he performed a sacrifice contrary to rules, whence this result arose.**

> Brahmā said:—
> 21. Thus commanded by Śiva, Vīrabhadra, hastened to bring the headless body of Dakṣa which he threw in front of Śiva.

> 22-23. O excellent sage, on seeing the headless body, Śiva, the benefactor of the worlds, spoke laughingly to Vīrabhadra—“Where is the head of Dakṣa?”, Vīrabhadra replied—“O lord Śiva, at that time itself, the head was consigned to fire by me.”

> 24-26. On hearing the words of Vīrabhadra, Śiva commanded the gods in the manner as mentioned before. After doing in accordance with what lord Śiva had said, Viṣṇu, the gods and I acquainted Bhṛgu with the same quickly. At the bidding of Śiva, they immediately joined the head of the sacrificial animal, the goat, with the body of Dakṣa.

> 27. When the head was joined and Śiva looked at it, Dakṣa regained his life and awoke as if from sleep.

> 28. On waking up he saw Śiva, the merciful, in front of him. Dakṣa stood there happy and joyful.

> 29. **Formerly his mind had been contaminated and affected by a great hatred towards Śiva. But now immediately after seeing him, his mind became pure like the autumnal moon.**

> 30. He wanted to eulogise Śiva but could not do so because of his affection, emotional disturbance and anxiety for his deceased daughter.

> 31. Then after regaining composure and peace of mind, the ashamed Dakṣa bowed and eulogised Śiva, the benefactor of the worlds.

> Dakṣa said:—
> 32. I bow to the great lord, the supreme being, the bestower of boons, the store of knowledge, the eternal. I bow to Śiva, the lord of the chief of Gods, always conferring happiness and the sole kinsman of the universe.

> 33. I bow to the lord of the universe, of cosmic form, the primordial Being and the form of Brahman itself. I bow to Śiva, the conceiver of world’s happiness and the greater than the greatest.

> 34. O lord, lord of Devas, be merciful. Obeisance to thee. O Śiva, the storehouse of mercy, forgive my faults.

> 35. O, Śiva, **Thou hast blessed me under the pretext of punishing me.** O lord, I have been wicked and foolish. Thy real nature I could not understand.

> 36. Today I have realised the truth. Thou art above all. Thou art served by Viṣṇu, Brahmā and others. Thou art the supreme Being known only through the Vedas.